# js getelementbyid returns null

Tags: javascript, asp.net, getelementbyid

getElementById is returning null but the list is populated. Any guesses of what is wrong?

HomePage.aspx and Map.js

```js
var Center = { lat: 20.452425, lng: -68.545446 };

function initMap() {
    
   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: Center
    });   
    populateMap()
    function populateMap()
    {
        var DiveSiteList2 = document.getElementById("DiveSiteList")
         for (var i = 0; i < DiveSiteList2.options.length; ++i)
        {...}
        

    }
    }
```

```html
<div id="ListHolder">
  <asp:ListBox class="ListBox" ID="DiveSiteList" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

HomePage.aspx.cs

```
    private DiveManager.DiveManager Manager;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Manager = new DiveManager.DiveManager();
        BindDiveList();
    }

    private void BindDiveList()
    {
       foreach (DiveSite DS in Manager.MasterDiveSiteList)
        {
            ListItem Item = new ListItem();
            Item.Text = DS.DiveSiteName;
            Item.Attributes.Add("Name", DS.DiveSiteName);
            Item.Attributes.Add("Latitude", DS.Latitude.ToString());
            Item.Attributes.Add("Longitude", DS.Longitude.ToString());
            Item.Attributes.Add("ID", DS.DiveSiteID.ToString());
            DiveSiteList.Items.Add(Item);
        }
    }
```

Page error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null
    at populateMap (Map.js:19)

Comment: There is probably no element with that id, which is why `getElementById` returns `null` (it fails silently).

Comment: I am not an ASP guy, but you should add an asp.net or asp.net-mvc tag to this. From a naive reading of this, it is not clear that the HTML page would in fact contain anything with theID DiveSiteList, just a bunch of IDs baed on the DS.DiveSiteID.

Comment: have you tried using `id` instead of `ID` (ie. lowercase). Also is your JS wrapped in an onload wait? Similarly, you're using `var DiveSiteList2` but then later `DiveSiteList`.. is this a typo?

Comment: haxxxton: yes, just a typo in the question. I tried the lower case, didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Check it
Just change here:

```
var DiveSiteList2 = document.getElementById('<%= DiveSiteList.ClientID %>')
```

```js
var Center = { lat: 20.452425, lng: -68.545446 };

function initMap() {
    
   
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 3,
        center: Center
    });   
    populateMap()
    function populateMap()
    {
        var DiveSiteList2 = document.getElementById('<%= DiveSiteList.ClientID %>')
         for (var i = 0; i < DiveSiteList2.options.length; ++i)
        {...}
        

    }
    }
```

```html
<div id="ListHolder">
  <asp:ListBox class="ListBox" ID="DiveSiteList" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
</div>
```

Comment: it didn't work but gave me the idea of looking at the page source code, and it turns out that the list box id was listed as "ContentPlaceHolder1_DiveSiteList"